# Android Studio Xml Preview White Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

My android studio preview is all white, regardless the objects that are in the activity.

[My current state](https://gyazo.com/6e3b8af775a8b8bc737bebd552fe5f5b)

Do you guys know maybe how can I fix it?
I'm running Android Studio 3.0 on Winodws 10 64 bit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: invalidate cache and rebuild your project

Comment: Did you checked using changing display devices from list in xml preview?

Comment: please add xml code so we can help you. Because I think anything wrong in xml code.

Answer (score 1):

In your styles.xml file, replace the main theme from

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

to

```
Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its only when you use preview? On real device is ok? Finger to the sky,but try to change the theme in editor to AppCompat or another theme that inherits it, add/remove tools in xml, check structure of xml elements(check is all views closed),or show us your XML, if on right side in preview window u see red button,click on it,then "refresh layout".

Answer (score 0):

Inside the preview box of the android studio at the right end, there is an icon with the symbol of an eye. Just click on that button and turn on show layout decorations. This worked for me.